# Añadir migration en c#

Tags: c#, api, postgresql, entity-framework-core

Estoy tratando de hacer 'migrations' en mi solución de C# pero me está resultando imposible. Estoy ejecutando el siguiente comando para poder ejecutarlo:

```
dotnet ef migrations add Initial -o ..\Data.Access.EF\Migrations\
```

La ruta está puesta a través de tabulaciones y el comando sacado de internet. El build inicia, y hace un succeeded, pero luego salta este error:

```
Your target project 'Presentation.API' doesn't match your migrations assembly 'Data.Access.EF'. Either change your target project or change your migrations assembly.
Change your migrations assembly by using DbContextOptionsBuilder. E.g. options.UseSqlServer(connection, b => b.MigrationsAssembly("Presentation.API")). By default, the migrations assembly is the assembly containing the DbContext.
Change your target project to the migrations project by using the Package Manager Console's Default project drop-down list, or by executing "dotnet ef" from the directory containing the migrations project.
```

Aquí ya me llego a perder ya que los pasos que tenía apuntados para hacer las migraciones de la base de datos eran los ya dados. Siento no poder dar más contexto, lo que si puedo hacer es dar el link de [github](https://github.com/AQM19/FuckOffendiditos_back).

---

EDIT

---

Aquí tengo el fragmento de código donde indica que el ensamblamiento debe hacerse en ese proyecto:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddDataBaseContextConfiguration(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(
            options => options.UseNpgsql( // Npgsql to Postgre
                   configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
                    builder =>
                    {
                        builder.MigrationsAssembly("Data.Access.EF");
                    }
                ));

            return services;
        }
```

---

EDIT 2

---

Vale, ya lo descubrí. Tenía que ejecutar el siguiente comando:

```
dotnet ef migrations add Initial -p ..\Data.Access.EF\ -c ApplicationDbContext
```

Con eso indicas que la ruta del proyecto que contiene la configuración necesaria sea la de Data.Access.EF y el -c ApplicationDbContext especifica el nombre del contexto de la base de datos.

Comment: *Either change your target project or change your migrations assembly.** Ya intentaste la sugerencia?

Comment: Si, y sigue dando el mismo error. A parte no debería cambiar el proyecto por defecto ya que es el que contiene las extensiones que usa la base de datos.

Comment: @AQMR Ya que lo has solucionado mételo como respuesta y acéptala para que la gente lo sepa. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

esto es lo que hago...
-dotnet ef migrations add "Migration Name"
-dotnet ef database update

//tienes que estar ubicado en la carpeta del proyecto